# Python - Outputting Variables To TXT file

Tags: python, output, text-files

Working on outputting text and variables to a `.txt` file through python. And it doesn't work.

```
f=open("Output.txt", "a")
f.write("Number Plate:", np ,"\n")
f.write("Valid:", valid ,"\n")
f.write("Speed:", speed ,"\n")
f.write("Ticket:", ticket ,"\n")
f.wrtie("Ticket Price:", ticketprice ,"\n")
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

This is the error that is given when i run it.

```
f.write("Number Plate:", np ,"\n")
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In the line, `f.write("Number Plate:", np ,"\n")` what is `np` ?

Comment: Error message should be clear enough for you to understand what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Please go through the syntax for `write` function at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.format`.

**Ex:**

```
f=open("Output.txt", "a")
f.write("Number Plate: {0}".format(np))
f.write("Valid: {0}".format(valid ))
f.write("Speed: {0}".format(speed ))
f.write("Ticket: {0}".format(ticket ))
f.write("Ticket Price: {0}".format(ticketprice ))
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

**Note**: `f.write` takes only a single argument, You are trying to pass 3`("Number Plate:", np ,"\n")`

Comment: You forgot `{}` in your `f.write("Valid: {}".format(valid ))`

Comment: @zvone. Thanks :)

Comment: And it would be better to either use `with open()...` or to put the whole file usage in `try: ... finally: f.close()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
with open("Output.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("Number Plate:" + str(np) + "\n")
    f.write("Valid:" + str(valid) + "\n")
    f.write("Speed:" + str(speed) + "\n")
    f.write("Ticket:" + str(ticket) + "\n")
    f.write("Ticket Price:" + str(ticketprice) + "\n")
    f.write("\n")
```

Explanation:

If you use `with open....` there is no need to explicitly specify the `f.close()`. And also in `f.write()` using string concatenation `+` you can get the required one.

Comment: @dominicXD hough: Is this what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **`str()`** function

> The **str()** function is meant to return representations of values which
>   are fairly human-readable.

**And your valid code will be like-**

```
f=open("Output.txt", "a")
f.write("Number Plate:" + str(np) + "\n")
f.write("Valid:" + str(valid) + "\n")
f.write("Speed:" + str(speed) + "\n")
f.write("Ticket:" + str(ticket) + "\n")
f.wrtie("Ticket Price:" + str(ticketprice) + "\n")
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

your code giving Error, `TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)`

*because-*

**`write()`** method takes only 1 argument, but you are providing 3 argument

*1) "Number Plate:" , 2) np and 3) "\n"*